# Non-Linear (Second Order) Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some hints for solving $yy''-(y')^2=xy^2$.

I noticed that the left hand side is close to $(yy')'$:

$yy''-(y')^2=xy^2\ \Leftrightarrow\ yy''+(y')^2-2(y')^2=xy^2\ \Leftrightarrow\ (yy')'-2(y')^2=xy^2$.

But I don't know how to continue expressing the terms as derivatives of some functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\frac {y'}{y}$ instead of $y'y$
$$yy''-(y')^2=xy^2$$
$$(\frac {y'}{y})'=x$$
Integrate
$$\frac {y'}y=\frac {x^2}2+k$$
$$\int \frac {dy}y=\int \frac {x^2}2+kdx$$
$$\ln y=\frac {x^3}6+k_1x+k_2$$
$$y(x)=k_2e^{\frac {x^3}6+k_1x}$$

Comment: Thank you Isham for this and for the other one I posted.

Comment: @Victor you're welcome...you were on the right track...

Answer (score 1):

Take the change of variable $z = \ln y$. So you would end up with the following relations
$$y = e^z$$
$$y' = z'e^z$$
$$y'' = e^z z'' + (z')^2 e^z$$
Upon substitution (all $e^z$'s will cancel out), leaving you with a $2^{nd}$ order differential equation, which is easy to solve:
$$z'' = x$$

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, great approach.